# List<List<Vector3>> full of duplicates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a function that reads a file line by line, calculates positionvectors and adds those vectors to a list.
Each of these `List<Vector3> positionPerFrame` is than added to a `List<List<Vector3>> _frame`

While each `positionPerFrame` is different in every loop of the forEach loop `_frames` only includes duplicates of the last `positionPerFrame` that was added, basically overwriting previously added entries.

```
List<string> frameData = new List<string> ();
        frameData.AddRange (rawDataFile.text.Split ("\n" [0]));

_frames.Capacity = frameData.Count;

foreach (string str in frameData) {
    positionPerFrame.Clear ();

   //previous code with calculations omitted
    positionPerFrame.Add (Vector3); // 15 times with 15 diff. vectors
    _frames.Add(positionPerFrame);
}
```

Now, when I print `_frames`, it's just 400 times the last `positionPerFrame` that was added and yet, when I call the function that sets the position of the 15 points, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of clearing and adding the same instance in the `positionPerFrame` variable, you should create a new instance since you are now reusing the same object over and over again. This might be true for your `Vector3` variable too.

```
foreach (string str in frameData) {
    positionPerFrame = new List<Vector3>();

    positionPerFrame.Add (Vector3);
    _frames.Add(positionPerFrame);
}
```

Comment: didnt mean to, misclicked.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you add a reference.
inside foreach do

```
positionPerFrame = new List<Vector3>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see how and where you create positionPerFrame but suspect the following:
You create positionPerFrame once and reuse it in your loop.
However,

```
_frames.Add(positionPerFrame);
```

does not copy the contents positionPerFrame to _frames but stores a reference to positionPerFrame in _frames.
You do this every time in your loop, thus filling up _frames with multiple references to the same positionPerFrame object.
At the same time, you alter positionPerFrame in the loop. As all elements of _frames point to the same positionPerFrame object, it seems like you are changing all contents of _frames.

Solution: create a new object for positionPerFrame in your loop.

Comment: Thank you very much